# ADB - Android emulator - Unable to record video - screenrecord not found with Android 5.11

Tags: adb, android-emulator, screencast

I installed android emulator, the SDK Tools v24.1.2, Android v5.1.1.
After all this the emulator is UP and I am able to run my app.

Where I ran into problem was while trying to do a screenrecord using adb. It gives the following error:

```
$ adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found
```

I can see screencap under `/system/bin` but no screenrecord.

I have the below installed:

- Android SDK Tools v24.1.2
- Android SDK Platform Tools v22
- Android SDK Build Tools v22.0.1
- Android v5.1.1 SDK Platform
- Google APIs Intel x86 System Image

Emulator is running for Nexus One.

I already found this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367309/android-screen-recording-screenrecord-not-found-on-the-command-line) and verified that I have required Android version. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments from Google in this bugtracker - emulator support of screenrecorder isn't going to happen in the near future due to hardware requirements/limitations.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682

Comment: thank you. I agree with some of those people on those threads. Wasted 3 hours of my time trying to make it work. But looks like they removed it as per this comment
https://code.google.com/u/118076936637373993553/

The adb android page still says screenrecord works though. Sigh

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was introduced - screenrecord option requires 4.4 or higher android version (based on API version).

Comment: Has nothing to do with current state of emulators, which do not support screen recording.